# Pandas fillna() method not filling all missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have rain and temp data sourced from Environment Canada but it contains some `NaN` values.

```
start_date = '2015-12-31'
end_date = '2021-05-26'
mask = (data['date'] > start_date) & (data['date'] <= end_date)
df = data.loc[mask]
print(df)
```

```
            date      time  rain_gauge_value  temperature
8760  2016-01-01  00:00:00               0.0         -2.9
8761  2016-01-01  01:00:00               0.0         -3.4
8762  2016-01-01  02:00:00               0.0         -3.6
8763  2016-01-01  03:00:00               0.0         -3.6
8764  2016-01-01  04:00:00               0.0         -4.0
...          ...       ...               ...          ...
56107 2021-05-26  19:00:00               0.0         22.0
56108 2021-05-26  20:00:00               0.0         21.5
56109 2021-05-26  21:00:00               0.0         21.1
56110 2021-05-26  22:00:00               0.0         19.5
56111 2021-05-26  23:00:00               0.0         18.5

[47352 rows x 4 columns]
```

Find the rows with a `NaN` value

```
null = df[df['rain_gauge_value'].isnull()]
print(null)
```

```
            date      time  rain_gauge_value  temperature
11028 2016-04-04  12:00:00               NaN         -6.9
11986 2016-05-14  10:00:00               NaN          NaN
11987 2016-05-14  11:00:00               NaN          NaN
11988 2016-05-14  12:00:00               NaN          NaN
11989 2016-05-14  13:00:00               NaN          NaN
...          ...       ...               ...          ...
49024 2020-08-04  16:00:00               NaN          NaN
49025 2020-08-04  17:00:00               NaN          NaN
50505 2020-10-05  09:00:00               NaN         11.3
54083 2021-03-03  11:00:00               NaN         -5.1
54084 2021-03-03  12:00:00               NaN         -4.5

[6346 rows x 4 columns]
```

This is my dataframe I want to use to fill the `NaN` values

```
print(rain_df)
```

```
             date      time  rain_gauge_value  temperature
0      2015-12-28  00:00:00               0.1         -6.0
1      2015-12-28  01:00:00               0.0         -7.0
2      2015-12-28  02:00:00               0.0         -8.0
3      2015-12-28  03:00:00               0.0         -8.0
4      2015-12-28  04:00:00               0.0         -7.0
...           ...       ...               ...          ...
48043  2021-06-19  19:00:00               0.6         20.0
48044  2021-06-19  20:00:00               0.6         19.0
48045  2021-06-19  21:00:00               0.8         18.0
48046  2021-06-19  22:00:00               0.4         17.0
48047  2021-06-19  23:00:00               0.0         16.0

[48048 rows x 4 columns]
```

But when I use the `fillna()` method, some of the values don't get substitued.

```
null = null.fillna(rain_df)
null = null[null['rain_gauge_value'].isnull()]
print(null)
```

```
            date      time  rain_gauge_value  temperature
48057 2020-06-25  09:00:00               NaN          NaN
48058 2020-06-25  10:00:00               NaN          NaN
48059 2020-06-25  11:00:00               NaN          NaN
48060 2020-06-25  12:00:00               NaN          NaN
48586 2020-07-17  10:00:00               NaN          NaN
48587 2020-07-17  11:00:00               NaN          NaN
48588 2020-07-17  12:00:00               NaN          NaN
49022 2020-08-04  14:00:00               NaN          NaN
49023 2020-08-04  15:00:00               NaN          NaN
49024 2020-08-04  16:00:00               NaN          NaN
49025 2020-08-04  17:00:00               NaN          NaN
50505 2020-10-05  09:00:00               NaN         11.3
54083 2021-03-03  11:00:00               NaN         -5.1
54084 2021-03-03  12:00:00               NaN         -4.5
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: you are filling `na` values of of one dataframe with another dataframes values, but the index is a different shape and therefore a different index. You should never do this.

Comment: Your `rain_df` has 48048 rows and its index seems to be sequential `range(0,48048)`. Now see the index for your `df` and `null` that has not been filled. These indices show there's no match for that data in `rain_df` so they can't be filled.

Comment: I guess I should set the date and time as index?

Comment: You could, and it would be much better in that it will fill in missing values for specific time by value for that specific time (which is much more meaningful than just any index), but if not all times from `null` are in `rain_df` then it's still not going to fill in all of the missing values (just the ones that can be found in the `rain_df`).

Comment: I checked `rain_df` for missing values and it doesn't contain any

Answer (score 0):

when `fillna`, you probably want a method, like fill using previous/next value, mean of column etc, what we can do is like this

```
nulls_index = df['rain_gauge_value'].isnull()
df = df.fillna(method='ffill') # use ffill as example
nulls_after_fill = df[nulls_index]
```

take a look at:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform pandas how you want to patch. It may be obvious to you want to use the "patch" dataframe's values when the date and times line up, but it won't be obvious to pandas. see my dummy example:

```
raw = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=[date(2015,12,28), date(2015,12,28)], time= [time(0,0,0),time(0,0,1)],temp=[1.,np.nan],rain=[4.,np.nan]))                                                                                                       
raw                                                                                                                          
         date      time  temp  rain                                                                                     
0  2015-12-28  00:00:00   1.0   4.0                                                                                     
1  2015-12-28  00:00:01   NaN   NaN 

patch = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=[date(2015,12,28), date(2015,12,28)], time=[time(0,0,0),time(0,0,1)],temp=[5.,5.],rain=[10.,10.])) 
patch
         date      time  temp  rain                                                                                     
0  2015-12-28  00:00:00   5.0  10.0                                                                                     
1  2015-12-28  00:00:01   5.0  10.0
```

you need the indexes of raw and patch to correspond to how you want to patch the raw data (in this case, you want to patch based on date and time)

```
raw.set_index(['date','time']).fillna(patch.set_index(['date','time']))
```

returns

```
                     temp  rain                                                                                         
date       time                                                                                                         
2015-12-28 00:00:00   1.0   4.0                                                                                                    
           00:00:01   5.0  10.0
```